# What are the Eclipse software requirments to run MercurialEclipse plug-in?

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, eclipse-plugin

I have installed MercurialEclipse in both Helios "Eclipse Classic 3.6.0" and Helios "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers".  Only in Classic does MercurialEclipse actually appear in the File->Import selections.

What are the additional Eclipse plug-ins that need to be installed in the Java IDE version in order to enable MercurialEclipse?  I tried installing the Eclipse SDK in that edition using the built-in software installer and then reinstalling MercurialEclipse but that did not work.

I don't mind simply using the Classic edition.  However, a co-worker has the Zend Studio branded Eclipse and MercurialEclipse does not work on his installation either.  I would like to be able to get the necessary Eclipse software added to his installation so that he can benefit from MercurialEclipse.

Comment: that's weird. I'm using JEE edition and it's installed just fine. Can you try it with JEE edition?

Comment: I tried JEE and it also worked just fine for me in that MercurialEclipse installed without error and then was available to me after restarting Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to get it to work, seemingly, after finding a clue on a board on the web that one user with the same issue dropped his Administrator privilege in Windows 7 down to Standard User and then it worked.  What I did was to add another local admin. account, drop my user account from Administrator to Standard User, re-installed [Eclipse IDE for Java Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/), and then installed MercurialEclipse.  This time it worked and MercurialEclipse was available!

My "solution" doesn't explain what the problem was but it did take care of the issue.  Besides, it is a good practice not to run as an Administrator anyway so this kills two birds with one stone.  I'll leave this question open for a while so that others can add information.

Comment: This is a p2 problem with installing on Windows 7, the install appears to be successful but the plugins are not present. Nothing to do with MercurialEclipse. Also I suggest you get the snapshot version of MercurialEclipse is has some additional important bug fixes in it.